# Timeout on server / delayed trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

iam working on asp.net game, where i need something like delayed trigger (it does not exists) or running thread on server side.

used tools:
mssql 2008 express
asp.net mvc3 (razor)

in simple i'm trying to do game like travian or some other web browser game, but iam stuck with attack. First player need to train units. Then he can pick enemy player and assign units to attack. Then the attack begins, and after period of time should be evaluated (when units reach the enemy player position on map). 
I don't know how to call the method after that period of time, asi it must be called even if user closes browser after declaring attack.

i found mssql WAITFOR but it is not suitable, as there can be multiple processes (attacks).

The best solution will be if i can make something like working thread on server side,. that will check if any of attacking units reached enemy player and fight should be calculated.

thank for Yours replies

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to **schedule** jobs or tasks that will be tracked and executed when they are due. You can come up with a solution from scratch for that, but this is a quite common problem, so you could look for a scheduling library that suits your needs. E.g. have a look at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

To decide what is the best solution for your concrete case try to think about the following requirements:

- Do you want to persist the scheduled jobs (if your server restarts, shall the jobs survive the restart)? I assume yes.
- Do you need an active "agent" (process, thread, etc.) to perform the jobs automatically when they are due (e.g. to send a notification email right away) or is it enough to execute/evaluate the jobs when any of the affected users come back and poll their status (execution on demand when you anyway execute something for the user).
- If you need an active agent you have to find a good place for hosting that. It can be the SQL Server Agent, it can be a windows service. The "agent" can live in the web application too, if you can assume that the web application is always "used" by the players and hence kept alive anyway, or it is not THAT critical anyway that the jobs are executed "immediately" as they are due.

Comment: The project is hosted on remote server (hosting server) and i don't have option to run such a program on it. I would prefer something supported by mssql server itself.

Comment: Why don't you run the scheduler in the web application then?

Comment: the minimum interval is 5minutes, i need precision in seconds